# Donwloading a large zip-file from FTP with Laravel Storage fails

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I want to download zip files (fromt 200mb up to 3GB) from an FTP-Server to the local directory of my applications server. Therefor I've written a job with takes the filename, constructs the relevant paths/directories and then streams the file from ftp to local directory. Unfortunately the job keeps failing for large files with the following message:

> Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException:
> App\Jobs\DownloadFileFromFtp has been attempted too many times or run
> too long. The job may have previously timed out. in
> /home/forge/staging.vehicle-service.faaren-global.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:648

I'm running the queue worker via `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0` so there should be no timeout.

This is my job:

```
private function downloadFIleFromFtp(): bool
{
    try {
        if(!file_exists(storage_path('app/temp/'))){
            mkdir(storage_path('app/temp/'));
        }

        $destination = storage_path('app/temp/' . $this->import->unique_filename);

        $ftpDisk = Storage::disk($this->import->disk);

        $stream = $ftpDisk
            ->getDriver()
            ->readStream($this->import->filename);

        file_put_contents($destination, stream_get_contents($stream), FILE_APPEND);
        return true;
    } catch(\Exception $ex){
        $log = ImportLog::createWithException($ex, "Download from ftp failed");
        $this->import->logs()->save($log);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What value does ``phpinfo()`` returns for ``max_execution_time`` and what kind of hosting/server you're running on?

Comment: @OMiShah it's a droplet on DigitalOcean, Ubuntu 20.04. with php7.3 and 30 seconds max execution time.. Okay, I will increase this value and test it again. Thought this value would be overwritten by `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0`

Comment: The error is what the queue says when it fails to process the job. Each job has its own error when it fails so it would be useful to know what that is. I suspect it's an out of memory error because you're trying to stream a 200mb - 3gb file to memory instead of streaming it with e.g. an `fopen` -> `fread` -> `fclose` combo, though to be sure you should check your PHP CLI logs

Comment: Is there an error log existing? Maybe the FTP adapter has errors or timeouts which cause that the task in queue fails.